# connect to xvfb remote to fix firefox headless crash?

Tags: nagios, remote, firefox, headless, selenium

I have firefox running in xvfb (for nagios monitoring with selenium) but firefox crashes on me since today

in ps:
/usr/lib/firefox-3.6.17/crashreporter /tmp/customProfileDira27173dd39e4467....

how can I see/fix the crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution here is to run [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) on the same display as Firefox so that you can at least see what Firefox is complaining about.

Comment: yup, got this working