# How to watch firefox/chrome running headlessly [under xvfb] on remote headless machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, remote-desktop, firefox, selenium, xvfb

I have my selenium tests running on a jenkins server installed on a ubuntu headless machine [remote on AWS] using xvfb buffer, there are times when the tests gives false failures may be because of resolution/time/configuration issues but they just work fine on local machine, 
To find the route cause, I want to connect to the remote machine and watch whats going on in firefox while test is running.
Have tried so far

> - installed ubuntu-desktop
> - installed x11Vnc on remote machine
> - vncviewer on local machine
> - connected both
> - ran tests on remote machine

but all it opens is a dark black window with no progress/firefox shown.

Have checked this too -[connect to xvfb remote to fix firefox headless crash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/273095/connect-to-xvfb-remote-to-fix-firefox-headless-crash#new-answer)
but no success yet!

Also tried : http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-desktop-vm-on-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: You should use `xvfb` and `ffmpeg` for recording the sessions: http://afterdesign.net/2016/02/07/recording-headless-selenium-tests-to-mp4.html